# In what order do one-sided t-tests in R compare two samples?

Tags: r, statistics, t-test, statistical-test

I want to use t.tests to compare samples of temperatures divided in 2 groups: summer and winter. I suppose that, if any difference is to be detected, it should be in the direction of summer temperatures being greater than winter, therefore I would use a one-sided t-test.

For example:
`t.test(sample1,sample2, alternative = "greater")`

Which sample is the test testing for being greater than the other?

Here is another code I'd like to use, to calculate the power for the comparison since groups do not have the same size:

`pwr.t2n.test(n1 = 44, n2 = 54, d = 0.5, sig.level = 5/100, power = NULL, alternative = 'greater')`

In this case, is the function testing n1 or n2 to be greater than the other?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: What did the help at `?t.test` say?

Comment: According to the help page, `alternative = "greater" is the alternative that x has a larger mean than y. For the one-sample case: that the mean is positive.`